# R Function for Identifying NA Values Incorrectly Entered as Zeroes

Tags: r

I have a data set with a number of columns like this:

```
pop <- data.table(group_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                   N = c(4588, 4589, 0, 4590, 4588), 
                   N_surv_1 = c(0, 0, 4264, 4266, 4264), 
                   N_surv_2 = c(3703, 0, 0, 3710, 3715), 
                   N_surv_3 = c(NA, 3054, 3159, 0, 0) )

   group_id    N N_surv_1 N_surv_2 N_surv_3
1:        1 4588        0     3703       NA
2:        1 4589        0        0     3054
3:        1    0     4264        0     3159
4:        1 4590     4266     3710        0
5:        1 4588     4264     3715        0
```

The number of rows per group varies and each row represents a measurement for an entity specified by group_id for a particular point in time. I believe the data was incorrectly entered such that in some cases an NA value indicates a missing value, but in other cases a 0 was entered to indicate an NA value. There are legitimate zero values in the dataset, but I can identify the erroneous ones by looking for differences in column values above a particular threshold. For example

```
1
3
5
0
3
```

Might be a legit zero but

```
50
46
50
0
47
```

probably wouldn't be.

I think the best solution then would be to look for a string of zeroes followed or proceeded by a large jump and relabel the zeroes as NA. How could I do something like this in R?

Comment: I think you will have to be more specific about how you plan to identify true zeros. As a start try `apply(pop, 2, diff)`. This will produce a table that represents subtracting the values in one row from the values in the next row. For example, subtracting row 1 from row 2 gives (0, 1, 0, -3703, NA). That will highlight jumps in the values that might signify a missing value rather than a true zero.

Comment: Is there any way to identify a stretch of zero values followed by a jump?

Answer (score 0):

dcarlson's advice is spot on.  You'll need to think harder on your definition of true zeros.

```
Library(data.table)

pop <- data.table(group_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                  N = c(4588, 4589, 0, 4590, 4588), 
                  N_surv_1 = c(0, 0, 4264, 4266, 4264), 
                  N_surv_2 = c(3703, 0, 0, 3710, 3715), 
                  N_surv_3 = c(NA, 3054, 3159, 0, 0) )
#Difference approach
pop[c(diff(N),NA)>100,N:=NA,by=group_id]
#This won't handle two zeros in a row that should both be NA.


pop <- data.table(group_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                  N = c(4588, 4589, 0, 4590, 4588), 
                  N_surv_1 = c(0, 0, 4264, 4266, 4264), 
                  N_surv_2 = c(3703, 0, 0, 3710, 3715), 
                  N_surv_3 = c(NA, 3054, 3159, 0, 0) )
```

This will -use a rolling mean with na.rm=TRUE and specify the cut-off value (here 100.)

```
pop[frollmean(N,3,fill = NA,na.rm=TRUE,align = "left")-N>100,N:=NA]
pop[frollmean(N,3,fill = NA,na.rm=TRUE,align = "right")-N>100,N:=NA]
```

Need to use the right and left rolling mean to get 'em all.
#But, this uses the column names an excessive number of times (6 times for one operation.) You're likely to generate a typo messing up your data table if you do that.

```
#Let's start again.
pop <- data.table(group_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                  N = c(4588, 4589, 0, 4590, 4588), 
                  N_surv_1 = c(0, 0, 4264, 4266, 4264), 
                  N_surv_2 = c(3703, 0, 0, 3710, 3715), 
                  N_surv_3 = c(NA, 3054, 3159, 0, 0) )

RollReplace <- function(dt,colName,maxDiffAllowed){
  dt[frollmean(get(colName),3,fill = NA,na.rm=TRUE,align = "left")-get(colName)>maxDiffAllowed,
     eval(colName):=NA]
  dt[frollmean(get(colName),3,fill = NA,na.rm=TRUE,align = "right")-get(colName)>maxDiffAllowed,
     eval(colName):=NA]
}

RollReplace(pop,colName='N',100)
RollReplace(pop,colName='N_surv_1',100)
```

Still, you want to be careful.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thanks for the answer! Much appreciated!